# SAS SID for Server

Tags: sas

I am installing SAS and have a valid license, for Windows Workstation.

I found the following at the link below:

> The operating system value in the SAS installation data file (SID
>   file) does not have to match the operating system of the machine that
>   SAS is installed on as long as the SAS client application is part of
>   the order that you are using.

http://support.sas.com/kb/49/003.html

Does this mean there is some way to change the SID file to allow this license to install on Windows Server? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You need a server license to install on a server - ask your administrator or SAS Support (be aware that server licenses are much more expensive!)

Comment: I need to install on a server OS, but I'm just looking for a "standalone" type of install. Enough to run a SAS script that converts some data from one format to another. Do I still need a server license?

Answer (score 0):

The page you're linking here is not related to `Base SAS` but to SAS client applications, when used in a client-server relationship.  This would be something like Enterprise Guide; something that itself doesn't do the work, but instead submits code to a server which does.

That page is saying that if (for example) you have a server license for SAS, you don't have to have a desktop license to install Enterprise Guide on a desktop.  You would have to have a desktop license to install (base) SAS on a desktop, though.

Comment: I need to install on a server OS, but I'm just looking for a "standalone" type of install. Enough to run a SAS script that converts some data from one format to another. Do I still need a server license? (Sorry, same comment as above.)

Comment: If you are installing on a server, then you need a server license.  The kind of license you are describing is likely significantly cheaper than the full package for a big server, but anything running on server-type hardware and/or a server OS requires a server license.  Talk to your SAS support representative for the details.  What you describe is pretty much what I work with on a daily basis [a server install that's otherwise more or less desktop SAS].